# Deleting PIA application

Tags: openvpn

I accidentally installed Private Internet Access application by clicking and opening the zipped file from their website. It is listed in my applications but I cannot delete it using terminal because I cannot find it listed. I have since installed my VPN the correct way but the earlier, wrong install that I did still causes a message to pop up in the right hand top corner saying it is connecting/disconnecting.Any way I can stop this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website that you used.

Answer (score 1):

It was installed by clicking on the package itself and put my username and password into the GUI, as I thought it could be installed just like it can on my phone and mac. So I cant see it in installed apps in the software centre even though it is in my applications.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website that you used.

Comment: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/    just the Linux d/l from this page. I will check the network settings like you suggested.

Comment: According to their website: rm -rf ~/.pia_manager/   should remove it, but other users have complained that the vpn's were left in place.  https://helpdesk.privateinternetaccess.com/hc/en-us/articles/219660167-Uninstalling-the-Linux-Beta-Client  If the vpns aren't listed in the network settings then check the file /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: Thanks. I think I worked it out. I looked in system settings startup items and it was listed there. So I unclicked it and deleted it and now it's gone from applications as well.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on how it was installed. 
If it was a browser extension then you can uninstall it from your browser settings. 
If it installed through the "software center" then run the software center and click "Installed". The down pointing arrow next to installed will show the sources to make it easier to find. Once you have found the package you can uninstall it.

Edit:

Also check for unwanted VPN connections by running 'system settings' and clicking 'network'.